# determine maxima or minima of $f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, maxima-minima

Let $f(x,y)=x^6+2x^2y-x^4y+2y^2$, then at $(0,0)$ have maxima, minima, or saddle point.

I have check $(0,0)$  is critical point but $f_{xx}f_{yy}-f^2_{xy}=0$.
How to comment on whether it's maxima or minima or saddle point at the origin?

Answer (score 1):

Along parabolas $y=x^2, y=-x^2,y=-0.5x^2$ are the values respectively
$$f(x,x^2)=x^6-2x^4-x^6+2x^4=0,$$
$$f(x,-x^2)=2x^6,$$ which is positive for the points close to $(0,0),$
$$f(x,-0.5x^2)=0.5x^4(3x^2-1),$$ negative close to $(0,0),$
therefore $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: I have read somewhere functions like f(x,y) we have to find two paths one along f(x,y)>0 and alone other one f(x,y)<0. then it is a saddle point, please correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)=x^6+2x^2y-x^4y+2y^2$

In a neighborhood around the origin, the lowest degree terms are going to dominate.  In this case, that would be the $2x^2y+2y^2$ terms.  We can just analyze these terms.

If $y<0$ and $|x^2|>|y|$ then $2x^2y+2y^2 < 0$ and that is less $f(0,0).$